# Invalid value for prop 'component' on <a> tag

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error saying an invalid value for prop 'component' on  tag.

Below is the code I have in my component.

```
<Link to="/posts" component={Posts}>
    See Posts
</Link>
```

[image]

What does this error mean?

Comment: Literally what it says.... that is not a valid prop for the Link tag...

Comment: Can you add what Posts refers to? Edit: nvm I was thinking this is a `Route` component - which is where you use `component` prop not on `Link`.

Comment: the component prop should be passed to the <Route /> not the <Link /> tag...

Comment: Thanks! Make sense now.  component should be passed to Route ... :) stupid mistake.. Thanks guys!

Comment: I understand what i was doing wrong.. however, just wondering why would this throw a warning saying that its an invalid prop?  what prompts it to throw that warning.  If i have a custom component and I pass some random prop to it, it doesn't result in a warning .. why does it happen here though?....

Comment: Just a suggestion, when you add an error to SO add it as text, not as an image (unless strictly necessary), so that it's easier to read, search, etc.

Comment: @psj01so what did you do? is there a code what we can see on how did you pass the props to Link?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your other question:

> I understand what i was doing wrong.. however, just wondering why
>   would this throw a warning saying that its an invalid prop? what
>   prompts it to throw that warning. If i have a custom component and I
>   pass some random prop to it, it doesn't result in a warning .. why
>   does it happen here though?

It's because the `Link` component passes all props it doesn't use to the `<a>` tag. React sees that you're assigning a `component` prop on the `<a>` and that it's an invalid prop for that element, so it throws a warning.

You can see this in the React Router source - it's a simple component.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js

To be clear, this has nothing to do with the PropTypes. As far as I know there's no option with PropTypes to throw an error when passed an unspecified prop.

Answer (score 0):

**Its too late when i answered. But this is the main theme avoiding this error **[image]

[enter link description here][2]

**Or you can check this to search with this link**
[2]: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation